# Using Vlookup inside Sumproduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table named "Open" that contains values of DPL_900, DP_950, etc. I want to calculate the sum of multi between quantity and each value of DPL_900, DP_950 which "Vlookup" in Open table. So I typed in the cell K98 that formula:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(K93:K97,VLOOKUP(L93:L97,Open,2,0))}.
```

I thought that formula would work but it does not.

[image]

Comment: Describe clearly what you are trying to achieve please. What is your desired result considering the sample in the screenshot?

Comment: Thank for responding. I have an example:  Value of DPL_900 is 10. Value of DP_950 is 5. Result is 6*10+8*5=140

Comment: That's relevant information you should include in the initial question. It's impossible to have guessed these values plus your desired result from the current status of your question. Please address that, see [ask] a question with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need any `VLookup()`. Use following formula. Here `Open` is table name with header.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B6,(Open[Cat]=C2:C6)*Open[Num])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your formula works perfectly. Is there any way if I use Name manager?

Comment: If you found the answer working then please accept (mark tick as green) it so that other user can know it helped you. In case of `Name Manager` I think have to use `INDEX()` formula with sumproduct.